# How to paginate users with more than 0 object of attribute boolean: false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, controller, pagination

How to paginate users with more than 0 `publish` challenges?

### controller

Attempt 1

```
@users, @alphaParams = User
  .select{ |user| user.challenges.publish > 0 }
  .alpha_paginate(params[:letter], {:pagination_class => "pagination-centered"}){|user| user.name}
```

Attempt 2

```
@users, @alphaParams = User
  .where(self.challenges.publish > 0)
  .alpha_paginate(params[:letter], {:pagination_class => "pagination-centered"}){|user| user.name}
```

Attempt 3

```
@users, @alphaParams = User.joins(:challenges)
  .where('challenges.publish > 0')
  .distinct
  .alpha_paginate(params[:letter], {:pagination_class => "pagination-centered"}){|user| user.name}
```

### model

```
scope :publish, ->{ where(conceal: false) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
users_with_published_challenges_scope = User
  .select('DISTINCT users.*')
  .joins(:challenges)
  .merge(Challenge.published)

@users, @alphaParams = users_with_published_challenges_scope
  .alpha_paginate(
    params[:letter], 
    :pagination_class => "pagination-centered"
  ) { |user| user.name }
```